# Why is my SharedPreference not saving my data?

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

The code below relates to my DatePicker method that you can choose a date and the TextView displays the date chosen.

I have a saveData and loadData function and when I go to save the data from my Datapicker it doesn't display the date chosen by the user after I go back into my Letter created which makes me believe that I could have inputted the wrong information or mixed them up between the Button and TextView. Not sure what could be wrong but it isn't saving which leads me to believe something is messed up.

```
        <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_timePicker"
                    android:text="What's the date?"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textTime"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="@tools:sample/date/ddmmyy"/>


  loadData()


  btn_timePicker.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }

    private fun saveData() {
        val insertedText = btn_timePicker.text.toString()
        val key1 = "STRING_KEY"
        val key2 = "BOOLEAN_KEY"

        textTime.text = insertedText
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.apply {
            with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
                putInt(key1, insertedText.toInt())
            }.apply()
            Toast.makeText(this@NewsActivity, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedString = sharedPreferences.getString("STRING_KEY", null)

        textTime.text = savedString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code here `putInt(key2, insertedText)`. The `insertedText` is a string but you're saving it as an `int`. Use `putString` instead. Also, I'll advise you make your preference keys constant so as to avoid errors.

Comment: They're already made constant by setting them to val or no?
Also, would I need to make an OnClick for my SharedPreferences, I don't know if I should put the OnClick on the DatePicker button itself or the Letter Saving within my app..

Comment: "They're already made constant by setting them to val", yes that's correct. But it's not when you're trying to read the value. This `"STRING_KEY"`

Answer (score 0):

```
insertedText is a String object. So You can't save it as an `int`.
```

If You want to save it as `String` then use this

```
putString(key2, insertedText)
```

Or, If You want to save it as `int` only then convert `insertedText` to int and then save it. Like this

```
putInt(key2, insertedText.toInt())
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfect, I updated my post with the new code, for some reason my DatePicker is still not being saved when a user-inputted value is entered. If you could see anywhere in my code why that might be happening it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used the 2nd Key anywhere if that could be an issue with why it's still not saving?

Comment: Have you tried getInt(key1, 0) instead of getString ?